# Definition of symmetric tensor is well defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I know that what a symmetric tensor is. I saw an exercise that made me a bit dubious about symmetric tensor.

Suppose $S$ is a symmetric $(1,1)$ tensor. then $g(SX,Y)=g(X,SY)$. In index notation $S_i{\ }^j=S_j{\ }^i$.

But I saw somewhere that claimed

> If a symmetric $(1,1)$ tensor is **symmetric in its indices with respect to  *every basis*** then it is a multiple of identity tensor. i.e. $S_i{}^j=\alpha\delta_i{}^j$.

Isn't the indices with respect to  every basis symmetric always? ($S_i{\ }^j=S_j{\ }^i$) If the answer is no  then I think the definition of symmetric  tensor is not well defined. Is it?

Comment: Your formula in index notation for a symmetric (1,1) tensor is incorrect. It holds only for an orthonormal basis. Choose an arbitrary basis and write everything with respect to the basis.

Comment: Another way to say this: A (1,1) tensor is symmetric if and only if the (0,2) tensor obtained by lowering the upper index is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some subtlety about this question which I'll try to address. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space and let $S$ be a "$(1,1)$-tensor". Since there are various different objects which can be identified with $(1,1)$-tensors (linear maps on $V$, linear maps on $V^{*}$, bilinear maps $V \times V^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and so on) let's be precise about what we mean and take $S$ to be a bilinear map $S \colon V \times V^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then, given a basis $(e_i)$ for $V$ (with $(e^j)$ the corresponding dual basis), we can construct
the square matrix $S_i{\ }^j := S(e_i, e^j)$. Note that the placement of indices tells us what type of object $S$ is.

Now, we can try and define $S$ to be "symmetric" if we have $S_i{\ }^j  = S_j{\ }^i $ for all $1 \leq i, j \leq n$. However, this turns out to be ill-defined as it is possible for this condition to hold with respect to one basis but not the other. This is not surprising: If you think about the tensor $S$ itself (and not the representing matrix), you see that it takes two arguments of different type (one in $V$, one in $V^{*}$) so a "symmetry condition" such as $S \left( v, \varphi \right) = S \left( \varphi, v \right)$ (where $v \in V$ and $\varphi \in V^{*}$) doesn't even compile. This is also reflected in Einstein's notation where in the equation
$S_i{\ }^j  = S_j{\ }^i$ one compares components where $i$ is both an upper and a lower index which represent different things.

Now let's assume that $V$ is endowed with an inner product $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ which is in particular a $(0,2)$-tensor represented by $g_{ij}$ with respect to some basis. Then you can use the metric to lower the $j$ index in $S_i{\ }^j$ to obtain $S_{ij} := S_i{\ }^k g_{kj}$. The resulting array $S_{ij}$ with two lower indices represents the $(0,2)$-tensor $\hat{S} \colon V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\hat{S} \left( v, w \right) = S \left( v, u \mapsto \left< w, u \right> \right)$. Then you can say that $S$ is symmetric if $S_{ij} = S_{ji}$ for all $1 \leq i, j \leq n$. This corresponds to the fact that $\hat{S}$ is symmetric in the sense that $\hat{S} \left( v, w \right) = \hat{S} \left( w, v \right)$ which now makes sense since both inputs of $\hat{S}$ are of the same type. Explicitly, you say that $S$ is symmetric if
$$ S_{ij} := S_i{\ }^k g_{kj} = S_j{\ }^k g_{ki} := S_{ji}$$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ and the representing arrays are taken **with respect to the same basis** $e_i$. Now, the important thing is that if this condition holds for one basis, then it holds for **all bases**, not only orthonormal ones! However, **only when the basis is orthonormal** we have $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ and so $S_{ij} = S_i{\ }^j$ and $S_{ji} = S_j{\ }^i$ and hence you can deduce that if $S$ is symmetric then it is represented by a symmetric matrix in an orthonormal basis.

So let me summarize. Let $S$ be a $(1,1)$-tensor so it can be represented naturally only by a "mixed-upper-lower-indexed-array" $S_i{\ }^j$. If there is no metric, one has no notion of symmetry of $S$. If there is a metric around, we can convert between the two types of indices. In which case, there is a notion of symmetry and we have:

1. $S$ is symmetric iff $\hat{S}$ is symmetric iff $S_{ij} = S_{ji}$ with respect to some basis iff $S_{ij} = S_{ji}$ with respect to every basis iff
   $S_i{\ }^j = S^j_{{\,\, }i}$ with respect to every basis (I'll let you figure out the meaning of the last equality by yourself).
2. $S$ is symmetric iff $S_i{\ }^j  = S_j{\ }^i$ with respect to some orthonormal basis iff $S_i{\ }^j  = S_j{\ }^i$ with respect to every orthonormal basis.

Comment: So in the case of (0,2) or (2,0) $S_{ij} = S_{ji}$ suffices wrt every basis. Yes?

Comment: @C.F.G: Yes, a $(0,2)$ tensor is symmetric iff $S_{ij} = S_{ji}$ in some/every basis.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually see what happens already on the level of linear algebra. For a symmetric bilinear form $b:V\times V\to\mathbb R$ there is an obvious notion of being symmetric. This corresponds to the fact that for each basis $\{v_i\}$ for $V$, the matrix $(b(v_i,v_j))_{i,j=1,\dots,n}$ is symmetric. Correspondingly, there is a natural notion of symmetry for $\binom02$-tensor fields on manifolds and this indeed amounts to $S_{ij}=S_{ji}$ with respect to any local frame.

In the presence of an inner product, you can convert a linear map $f:V\to V$ to a symmetric bilinear form $b:V\times V\to\mathbb R$ via $b(v,w)=\langle f(v),w\rangle$. Then symmetry of $b$ is equivalent to $\langle f(v),w\rangle=\langle v,f(w)\rangle$. However, the matrix $b(v_i,v_j)$ coincides with the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to the basis $\{v_i\}$ only if the basis orthonormal. Otherwise, you would have to use the dual basis with respect to the inner product in one entry of $b$. So symmetry of the linear map is equivalent to symmetry of a matrix representation with respect to an orthonormal basis but not with respect to a general basis. There is a counterpart to this on Riemannian manifolds, and the "good" condition in the Riemannian setting is that $g_{ik}S^k_j$ is symmetric in $i$ and $j$.